# Why $\det(A^{-1}) = 1/\det(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction on how I could start answering the following question:

> Based on the fact that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ for all square $n \times n$ matrices $A,B$, explain in every detail why:
>   $$\det(A^{-1}) = 1/\det(A).$$

Comment: Take $B=A^{-1}$ and the fact that $\det(I)=1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the matrix A is invertible, we know that:

$$AA^{-1} = I$$

$$\text{det}(AA^{-1}) = \text{det}(I)$$

Now we use $\text{det}(A*A^{-1}) = \text{det}(A)*\text{det}(A^{-1})$ and $\text{det}(I) = 1$ :

$$\text{det}(A)*\text{det}(A^{-1}) = 1  \implies \text{det}(A^{-1}) = 1/\text{det}(A)$$

Comment: That actually makes sense to me now. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You're welcome. It's always a pleasure to help.